# How to use React v16 without a build process

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React v15 I can easily do the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>React v15</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="divContainer"></div>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.6.2/dist/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.6.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/jsx">
            var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
                render: function() {
                    return <h2>Hello World !</h2>;
                }
            });


            ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />
                , document.getElementById('divContainer')
            )
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Once I reference react@16, react-dom@16 it no longer works, I understand that React.createClass() has been deprecated and removed. So what is its replacement?

I need a minimalist way of doing the same ***without*** a build process e.g. browserify, webpack, require, import, etc. I just want to reference libraries via a CDN or locally as I have shown in the example.

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal/issues/367

Comment: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#packaging and https://unpkg.org/pkg/create-react-class/. About 60s on Google.

Comment: No idea, can we start at the beginning? I've already seen those references prior to posting, How do i even use import React from 'react' or var React = require('react') in the Browser only ? how do i use the create-react-class drop in replacement ? I'm afraid you are dealing with a plain js dummy here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you include React 16 libs you can access the `React` instance directly and extend `React.Component`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>React Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/jsx">
    class MyApp extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <span>Hello world</span>;
      }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById('app'));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OMG, it actually works ! how simple is that. :-) nowhere to be found in the official docs, blogs, or out in the wild.